# Change-Making Problem Solution

Tags: java, calculator, change-making-problem

Please take a moment and review my code and tell me how I did. This is the first time in my class (CSC 111) I've been given an assignment in which I had to use a lot of my own resources and develop most of it on my own.

> Write an application that prompts for and reads a double value
>   representing a monetary amount. Then determine the least
>   number of each bill and coin needed to represent that amount,
>   starting with the highest. Assume that ten dollars is the
>   maximum size needed.
>   For example, if the value 47.63 is entered the program should
>   display
>
> - 4 ten dollar bills
> - 1 five dollar bills
> - 2 one dollar bills
> - 2 quarters
> - 1 dimes
> - 0 nickels
> - 3 pennies

My code works mostly flawlessly (I believe). I would like to hear other people's opinion on my solution. I understand it probably isn't the most efficient out there. How can it be improved? Are there things to watch out for?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Assignment01
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    /* Define Constants */

    BigDecimal tenDollar = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);
    BigDecimal fiveDollar = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);
    BigDecimal oneDollar = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
    BigDecimal quarter = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.25);
    BigDecimal dime = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.10);
    BigDecimal nickel = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.05);
    BigDecimal penny = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.01);


             /* Get Input From User */

    System.out.print("Please enter the amount to be converted: ");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal money = scan.nextBigDecimal();

    NumberFormat usdFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    usdFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    usdFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    System.out.println("Amount you entered: " + usdFormat.format(money));

            /* Begin Processing and Displaying Information */

    BigDecimal tenDollarNext = money.divideToIntegralValue(tenDollar);
    System.out.println(tenDollarNext.intValue() + " Ten Dollar Bills");

    BigDecimal fiveDollarNext = money.subtract(tenDollar.multiply(tenDollarNext));
    BigDecimal i = fiveDollarNext.divide(fiveDollar);
    System.out.println(i.intValue() + " Five Dollar Bills");

    BigDecimal oneDollarNext = fiveDollarNext.subtract(fiveDollar.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i.intValue())));
    BigDecimal f = oneDollarNext.divide(oneDollar);
    System.out.println(f.intValue() + " One Dollar Bills");

    BigDecimal quarterNext = oneDollarNext.subtract(oneDollar.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(f.intValue())));
    BigDecimal q = quarterNext.divide(quarter);
    System.out.println(q.intValue() + " Quarters");

    BigDecimal dimeNext = quarterNext.subtract(quarter.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(q.intValue())));
    BigDecimal d = dimeNext.divide(dime);
    System.out.println(d.intValue() + " Dimes");

    BigDecimal nickelNext = dimeNext.subtract(dime.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(d.intValue())));
    BigDecimal n = nickelNext.divide(nickel);
    System.out.println(n.intValue() + " Nickels");

    BigDecimal pennyNext = nickelNext.subtract(nickel.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(n.intValue())));
    BigDecimal p = pennyNext.divide(penny);
    System.out.println(p.intValue() + " Pennies");

    }
}
```

Comment: Using `BigDecimal` is probably over-engineering things.  For this scale of problem it is usually better to work in cents, not dollars, and use either `int` or `long` to hold the number of cents.  An `int` will go up to $21,474,836.47 while a long will go up to $92,233,720,368,547,758.07.  Given the nature of the problem, I suspect an `int` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>     BigDecimal money = scan.nextBigDecimal();
> ```

The specification said

> reads a double value representing a monetary amount.

However, `BigDecimal` is the correct type to represent a monetary amount. There's a case to be made for using `scan.nextDouble()` to comply with the spec and then converting it to `BigDecimal`. There's also a case to be made that you should talk to the person who set the task and suggest improving the spec.

---

> ```
>     BigDecimal tenDollarNext = money.divideToIntegralValue(tenDollar);
>     System.out.println(tenDollarNext.intValue() + " Ten Dollar Bills");
>
>     BigDecimal fiveDollarNext = money.subtract(tenDollar.multiply(tenDollarNext));
>     BigDecimal i = fiveDollarNext.divide(fiveDollar);
> ```

Why the inconsistencies? `tenDollarNext` and `fiveDollarNext` aren't analogues of each other, and one uses `divideToIntegralValue(...)` where the other uses `divide(...).intValue()`.

---

There are seven chunks of code dealing with seven values of token which are virtually identical. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself): use a loop.